# Dealing with missing values when calculating weighted mean

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(5, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA),
                         c(NA, 2, 2, NA, 0.5, 0.5), 
                         c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                         c(1, 1, 1, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33)))
colnames(df) <- c("V1", "V2", "V3", "W1", "W2", "W3")
```

I would like to add a weighted mean to the dataframe, discarding the NA when they exist. For example, in the first line, we would only take V1 and W1 to calculate the weighted mean.

My final dataframe would look like this:

```
   V1 V2  V3  W1   W2   W3   Wmean
1   5 NA  NA   1   NA   NA       5
2  NA  2   2  NA  0.5  0.5.      2
3  NA NA  NA  NA   NA   NA      NA
4   1  1   1  .33  .33  .33      1
```

Note that the weighted mean is calculated as such:
Wmean = (V1*W1 + V2*W2 + V3*W3)/(W1 + W2 + W3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can gather indices of columns with "V" and "W" separately and then `apply`, `weighted.mean` for each row ignoring the `NA` values.

```
V_index <- startsWith(names(df), "V")
W_index <- startsWith(names(df), "W")
df$WMean <- apply(df, 1, function(x) 
                  weighted.mean(x[V_index], x[W_index], na.rm = TRUE))

df

#  V1 V2 V3   W1   W2   W3 WMean
#1  5 NA NA 1.00   NA   NA     5
#2 NA  2  2   NA 0.50 0.50     2
#3 NA NA NA   NA   NA   NA   NaN
#4  1  1  1 0.33 0.33 0.33     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using:

```
df$Wmean <- rowSums(df[1:3] * df[4:6], na.rm = TRUE) / rowSums(df[4:6], na.rm = TRUE)
```

gives:

> ```
> > df
>   V1 V2 V3   W1   W2   W3 Wmean
> 1  5 NA NA 1.00   NA   NA     5
> 2 NA  2  2   NA 0.50 0.50     2
> 3 NA NA NA   NA   NA   NA   NaN
> 4  1  1  1 0.33 0.33 0.33     1
> ```

If you don't know the positions of the `V` and `W` columns beforehand, you can do (like @Ronak does with `startsWith`):

```
Vi <- grep("^V", names(df))
Wi <- grep("^W", names(df))

df$Wmean <- rowSums(df[Vi] * df[Wi], na.rm = TRUE) / rowSums(df[Wi], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also replace NA with 0s and do it this way:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
df$mean = ((df$V1 * df$W1) + (df$V2 * df$W2) + (df$V3 * df$W3))/(df$W1 + df$W2 + df$W3)
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2 V3   W1   W2   W3 mean
1  5  0  0 1.00 0.00 0.00    5
2  0  2  2 0.00 0.50 0.50    2
3  0  0  0 0.00 0.00 0.00  NaN
4  1  1  1 0.33 0.33 0.33    1
```